# Need to format textfield to currency format as user types in

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` where the user enters an amount.
I want to have the field update in `locale` currency format with press and lift up of each number entered.
Hope I have made myself clear. I have researched the site for hours but I cannot get a workable solution.

OK I have since been able to get close to a solution. I have implemented the UITextFieldDelegate and used the following code.

This works fine on the first time and as long as I clear the field and enter a fresh number each time. However, when I simply use the number that is already entered and used previously, the app crashes. I realise that EnterText.text is now in a Currency format and therefore the app crashes when the field is re-used in its new format. My question is how do I strip the $ and the commas from the field so that it would be reused multiple times. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    let curr = NumberFormatter()
    curr.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    curr.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
    curr.locale = NSLocale.current

    EnterText.text = curr.string(from: Int(EnterText.text!)!)
```

Comment: I am using Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use *NSNumberformatter* to convert your text to that of a currency format.

In order to do it as the user types, you might try and implement it in the *shouldchangecharactersinrange* delegate method.

This may possibly be one solution.

Comment: I have really no idea how to implement the code as I am new to Swift. Any help would be appreciated